# jstree callback load and select looping

Tags: javascript, jstree

I seem to be getting into a loop when trying to dynamically load data.

```
select_node -calls-> refresh -triggers-> select_node => death-spiral
```

Perhaps I need a different event or a different approach? My scenario is that I'm gathering data from multiple sources, and in some cases computing derived values. Hence I'm using a callback function

```
$('#theTree').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : function (node, cb) {
           // my code that figures out the data for different node.id values
     }
```

I populate the tree with just the top-level items, the idea being that when the user clicks on the item we refresh the subtree.

```
 $("#theTree").on('select_node.jstree',
            function(e, data) {
                $('#theTree').jstree(true).refresh_node(data.node.id);
                $('#theTree').jstree(true).open_node(data.node.id);
        }
     );
```

As expected, when refresh_node() my callback is called and some data is returned, the problem  is that this seems to trigger the select_node event again.

Suggestions please!

Comment: Wouldn't a AJAX call for loading each node on expand solve your problem. You could do this with a callback to core.data.url, or do you refresh a node's children every time it is selected ?

Comment: @Stephen S - yes, that's more or less what I ended up with, basic loading happening on expand, firing refresh when my logic needed it and a context menu so that the user can request a reload for some other cases. No loading in the "selected" event itself.